# UITabbar orientation issue

Tags: ios4, orientation, uitabbar

I have a tabBarController which contain two tab, i would like 1 tab is support orientation but another one not,how to do that? i have tried the code:

@implementation UITabBarController (CustomTabbar)

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

  ```
   if(self.tabBarController.selectedIndex==1){


      NSLog(@"rotate");
      return YES;
  ```

  }
  else
      {

  ```
  NSLog(@"no rotate");
  return  NO;
  ```

  }

}
@end

but after i rotating the view2 to landscape mode and back to view1, view1 become landscape as well until i rotate it back to potrait,but the thing i need is view1 always remain potrait when it appear,can help?

Regards,

sathish

Answer (score 0):

On *the view controller that you dont want rotating*, make sure that on the:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

You return NO;

You are returning it for the tabBar controller, not the actual viewController.

Answer (score 0):

When using a UITabBar controller, all orientation messages goes to the tab bar and stop there.

So, to accomplish what you are trying to do, you have to create a new class inherited from UITabBarController and use that instead.

```
@interface CustomUITabBarController : UITabBarController
```

After that you have 2 options to control the orientation of your controllers and both of them you will have touse the *shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation* selector.

You can either use the tab bar current selected index to return YES or NO for the orientation

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{

    if(self.selectedIndex == 0) {
        return NO;
    } else {
        return YES;
    }

}
```

OR you could let the controller decide for itself (as you were trying to do before)

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{

    if (self.selectedViewController) {
        return [self.selectedViewController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation];
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}
```